# Why is senti_classifier not giving any polarity?

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am stuck in a small thing. I need the polarity of words using the senti_classifier module in python. I am doing the following:

```
from senti_classifier import senti_classifier
senti_classifier.polarity_scores(["good"])
```

This gives me (0,0) as the positive and negative score. Infact the score are zero for anything and everything.

While downloading corpus using nltk.download(), I downloaded /corpora/sentiwordnet and corpora/wordnet/ and tokenizers/punkt/

I am not sure where am I going wrong!

Comment: From your example, it doesn't look you are actually giving the senti_classifier module a training dataset.  Can you post your full code set for review?

Comment: It is not suppose to receive any training data. It uses an existing library given by nltk. It is only a wrapper around that library.